# Belonging to a hierarchy

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, tree, hierarchy

I have a JPA entity representing a tree of product categories:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="gusti")
@NamedQueries({ 
    @NamedQuery(name="selectAll", query="select c from Gusto c left join fetch c.children left join fetch c.parent")
})
public class Gusto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String nome;

    @Lob
    private String descrizione;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private List<Gusto> children = new LinkedList<Gusto>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "parent_id",
        insertable=false,
        updatable=false
    )
    private Gusto parent;

    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy="gusto",
        cascade=CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch=FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private List<Prodotto> prodotti = new ArrayList<Prodotto>();

// ... 
}
```

And here's the product entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="prodotti")
public class Prodotto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    private String nome;

    @Lob
    private String descrizione;

    @ManyToOne
    private Gusto gusto;

// ...
}
```

Let's suppose my Gusto's tree to be like that:

```
Fruit
|_ Blackberry
|_ Orange

Vegetable
|_ Potato
```

I have some products whose Gusto is "Fruit" (the mother object) and other products "under" the "Orange" Gusto.

I am building a page which must show all the Fruit's products. 
So I have to include both the products directly under "Fruit" and the ones under "Orange".

The "prodotti" list does contain only the products directly related to that single Gusto.

How can I include in my query the products associated to the descendant Gustos?

I thought about having a method who traverses the tree and adds to the returning list all the products found. Is there a way to retrieve them with a single query or other techniques?

Thank you